# Converting SQL Server class vb to c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

How can I convert this code line

```
 Public Sub New()       
   /*'StoredProcedure USE*/
    MyBase.New(ConnectionStrings("MSSQL_DBConnectionString").ToString, "")
    Me.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
    Me.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
    Me.DeleteCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
    Me.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
End Sub
```

I'm also try to http://converter.telerik.com/ but not working its result.

```
public New() :base(ConnectionStrings("MSSQL_DBConnectionString").ToString, ""){
this.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
this.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
this.DeleteCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
this.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the error you get? Sure that you are not missing some parenthesis after `.ToString`? So `.ToString()`.

Comment: What does the error say? Additionally, there might be wrong bracket used `() -> []` for connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enter valid VB code into any converter to get a meaningful result (your comment is not a VB comment).
The C# equivalent constructor is the following, but the class name is unknown - replace "class name" with the name of the enclosing class:

```
public <class name>() : base(ConnectionStrings["MSSQL_DBConnectionString"].ToString(), "")
{
   ///*'StoredProcedure USE*/
    this.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
    this.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
    this.DeleteCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
    this.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
}
```